# Gmail "Can't attach empty file"

Tags: android, email-attachments

My app creates a PDF using iText library (template PDF with forms which are filled) and I want to then attach it to an email to send. When I try to attach the file I get the error `Can't attach empty file` in the Gmail app. Have also tried with the HTC email app and Touchdown email app - both of which just don't attach anything and give no error.

**Creating the PDF:**

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

// Fill all PDF forms here (theres quite a few)

        stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
}
```

**Attempting to attach file and send email:**

```
public void sendMail(){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent .setType("*/*");
    emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "blah@gmail.com");
    emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(dest));
    emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
}
```

Where `dest` is the path and filename of the file in question. I know the path and filename in `dest` are ok as this is the var used to save the file (which I can view fine on both the device and on a PC).

**Gmail logcat:**

```
06-26 00:24:48.901  14476-14476/? E/Gmail﹕ Error adding attachment
    com.android.mail.utils.b: Cannot attach empty attachment
            at com.android.mail.ui.ComposeAttachmentTileGrid.a(SourceFile:62)
            at com.android.mail.compose.c.b(SourceFile:1933)
            at com.android.mail.compose.c.c(SourceFile:2063)
            at com.android.mail.compose.c.a(SourceFile:7992)
            at com.android.mail.compose.c.q(SourceFile:759)
            at com.android.mail.compose.c.onCreate(SourceFile:4830)
            at com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail.onCreate(SourceFile:194)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: "I know the path and filename in dest are ok as this is the var used to save the file" -- that does not necessarily mean that it is a valid `Uri` value that can be parsed. Use `File` objects, not strings, to represent file paths. Then, you can use `Uri.fromFile()` and be better assured of getting a working `Uri` value. You may wish to examine what the `Uri.parse()` result is and see if it looks reasonable (e.g., has a `file` scheme). Also, hold onto the `FileOutputStream` and, if iText lets you, call `getFD().sync()` before you `close()` it.

Comment: Did you check if the Library is actually creating the file to the given `dest` ? Try to read the file and see if there is something wrong.

Comment: @osayilgan "I know the path and filename in dest are ok as this is the var used to save the file (which I can view fine on both the device and on a PC)"

Comment: Then It's clearly the Uri issue. Give it try to CommonsWare's Suggestion. And Log some more data, e.g what do you get with the `Uri.parse(dest)`

Comment: Thanks both - the `Uri.parse()` didn't have a alid `File` scheme. Working now

Comment: Have the same issue. I actually believe this is a bug in Google's new Gmail app. I can send data to any other app (using Uri.fromFile and Uri.parse) I have on my phone without a problem, but Gmail fails. There is actually a bug report on Google's forums where a user complains that Google's own Contacts-app is not able to share contacts using Gmail.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue. CommonsWare's comment above resolved it.!

Create a File object and generate a Uri using Uri.fromFile() method.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Comment: I have exactly the same thing in my code, yet it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: OK I solved it. Your solution will work if file is in external directory. If it is in private directory where only app has access, Gmail will throw can't attach empty file.

Comment: Uri.parse(imagePath) was not working, but above solution is working fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem on Nexus 5 with Android 6 (the same code worked on my Nexus 6 with Android 6), found explanation and working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32982050/534898