# Android 6: cannot share files anymore?

Tags: android, android-intent, share, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am sharing an image, and this code works properly for devices before Android 6:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mFilename));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, mChooserTitle));
```

However I get the toast error "**can't attach empty files**" when I try to share using Android 6.

I verified that the file exists and it's not zero-length.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Are you getting this `Toast` before or after the chooser? If after, what app did you choose? Also, where is `mFilename` pointing, exactly?

Comment: After the chooser, it happens with every app I tried. At least with Gmail and Hangout.

Comment: mFilename is inside the `getExternalCacheDir()`, starting with `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/`

Comment: Have you run Gmail and Hangouts yet, on their own? If not, they will not have access to external storage, until you (the user) go through their runtime permissions request logic.

Comment: Yes! you are right!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I enabled the external storage permission of Gmail, and now it works!!!!!!

Comment: although it seems very silly to me that Gmail doesn't ask for the permission when I attempt to share

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One limitation of the Android 6.0 runtime permission system is that there will be corner cases that cause problems. What you encountered is one: trying to share a file on external storage to an app that does not have the runtime permission checks in place for that particular UI path.

I say that this is a "corner case" because, for this bug in the receiving app to affect the user, the user cannot have previously used that app and granted the necessary permission. Either:

- The user has never used that app before, yet it still trying to share content to it, or
- The user revoked the permission via Settings, but did not realize that it would break this bit of functionality

Both of those are low probability events.

You, as the sender, have two main options:

1. Switch away from using `file://` `Uri` values, in favor of a file-serving `ContentProvider` like `FileProvider`, so the permission is no longer needed, or
2. Just living with the corner case

Comment: Ok, I implemented the FileProvider, and it works fine!

Comment: @DanieleB: FWIW, I wrote up [a blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/10/07/runtime-permissions-files-action-send.html) about this.

Answer (score 43):

I solved it by implementing a `FileProvider`, as suggested by @CommonsWare

You first need to configure a FileProvider:

- first, add the `<provider>` to your file manifest XML

  ```
  <provider
      android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="com.myfileprovider"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
  </provider>
  ```
- second, define your file paths in a separate XML file, I called it "**file_provider_paths.xml**"

  ```
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <external-path name="share" path="/" />
  </paths>
  ```

you can find the complete explanation in this [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

after you have set up your file provider in XML, this is the code to share the image file:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "com.myfileprovider", new File(mFilename));
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, mChooserTitle));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this - it helped me a great deal and works perfectly now.  They only thing I had to work out was getting the path correct to the file.

Comment: String filename=mCSVname.getText().toString()+".csv";
 File filelocation = new File(getExternalFilesDir (null), filename);
 Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "com.myfileprovider", filelocation);

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you don't need to have a ContentProvider / FileProvider . You can simply add the flag that grants read permission on the uri that is shared. 
Specifically, `share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`
 should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I used to workaround this issue was to get content provider style URI using `MediaScannerConnection` right after you wrote your file to the public directory:

```
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {imageFile.toString()}, yourMimeType, new OnScanCompletedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                //uri = "content://" style URI that is safe to attach to share intent
            }
        });
```

This may be a shorter solution for your needs.