# Share file from my activity to another app using FileProvider not working

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sharing, android-fileprovider

I am trying to share an mp3 file created in my app using the FileProvider. I followed the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) and [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981194/android-6-cannot-share-files-anymore), but it is not working: for example, gmail says "Can't attach empty file".

The mp3 files are saved in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyApp"`.

I added the provider to the manifest:

```
<provider
   android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
       android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Added the `file_provider_paths.xml` to res:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="share" path="MyApp/" />
</paths>
```

And added this method to my activity:

```
public void ShowShareChooser(String filename)
{
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    File f = new File(filename);
    Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.myapp.fileprovider",f);
    String type = getContentResolver().getType(fileUri);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,fileUri);
    shareIntent.setType(type);
    //shareIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri,type); // another failed attempt
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share song"));
}
```

When `filename` is `"/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/Audio.mp3"`, the resulting `fileUri` is `content://com.myapp.fileprovider/share/Audio.mp3`. The `type` is `audio/mpeg`.

I am targeting API 22, and testing this on a Nexus 5 (6.0.1).

Comment: As test try to open an input stream for the file uri yourself.

Comment: Does your app lack the permission to read from external storage?

Comment: thanks guys, I was just dumb. I stubbornly looked for the bug in this code because I read, during early researches, that sharing a file without the FileProvider would not work anymore. It turned out it was a new bug in another place of the code...

Answer (score 1):

As it often turns out, it was a stupid mistake on my part. The file was not created anymore because of a new bug somewhere else in the code, while I assumed it was there. The code works indeed fine, I'll leave it here for future reference (and as a personal memento).