# Share option not working for Marshmallow [android]

Tags: android

I fetch images from Json and display it in a gridview. On select an image, image enlarges to fullscreen and share option is available. As I click on share option, on phones above API 22, loading bar is not dismissing. It works well till Lollipop. Dont know why its not working in Marshmallow.

Here is the code

```
    public void share(View view){
    // Get access to the URI for the bitmap
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Displaydemo.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    niv1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgNetwork);
    Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(niv1);
    if (bmpUri != null) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"share");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Datas.Address );
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are facing mashmallow Runtime permission issue. please refer to this post [Android 6: cannot share files anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981194/android-6-cannot-share-files-anymore)

Also if are using the v4 Support Library u should use ShareCompat for sharing instead  https://medium.com/google-developers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b#.wnlh9s3n7

Comment: how to set up path xml file.

Comment: @Sreepulari what do u mean by "how to set up path xml file"?

Comment: set the path res/xml/filepath.xml

Answer (score 0):

> 

String   path =   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + File.separator +file_name;

File   file_ =new File(path);

private void shareFile( File file_) {
Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

```
    intentShareFile.setType(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file_.getName()));
    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.parse("file://"+file_.getAbsolutePath()));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share File"));


}
```