# Android - Unable To Add Email Attachments Using FileProvider

Tags: java, android, android-intent, email-attachments, android-fileprovider

I'm attempting to add multiple attachments to an email using a FileProvider as documented in the Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) and a SO post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981194/android-6-cannot-share-files-anymore).

The problem is I continuously get an error from Gmail stating "One or More files cannot be attached due to zero file size" however I've followed the documentation precisely:

### AndroidManifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.collision.man.collisionman"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
     </meta-data>
</provider>
```

### FilePaths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="share" path="/" />
</paths>
```

### SendActivity.java:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
//   sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[{"carl@collisionman.com"});
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "CollisionMan Damage Estimate");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);

ArrayList<Uri> uriList = null;
try {
    uriList = getUriListForImages();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriList);
Log.d("TAG", "Size of the ArrayList :: " + uriList.size());

SendActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));

//}
}

private ArrayList<Uri> getUriListForImages() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<Uri>();

    String imageDirectoryPath = getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DirName";
    File imageDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DirName");
    String[] fileList = imageDirectory.list();
    if (fileList.length != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            try {
                Uri u = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.collision.man.collisionman", new File(imageDirectoryPath + fileList[i]));
                uriList.add(u);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return uriList;
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

    //        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + picture_directory);
    File storageDir = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DirName");
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        File imageDirectory = new File("/sdcard/DirName/");
        imageDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

The strange part is my uriList contains all valid URI paths for the files I'd like to send - Gmail simply will not allow them to attach - so I'm thinking this is some sort of issue with the FileProvider - but I really have no idea.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are `imageDirectoryPath + fileList[i]` is creating a string like `/sdcard/DirnameFilename` when you really want `/sdcard/Dirname/Filename`.