# Can't share attached image from local folder into marshmallow and more version?

Tags: android

Can't attached image in Facebook and other social service and also set XML file

```
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

java file

```
 Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/fildername" + images29.png);
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          intent.setType("image/png"); 

      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri); 
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981194/android-6-cannot-share-files-anymore

Comment: That will not even compile.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write like below.

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile("/sdcard/fildername" + images29.png);
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          intent.setType("image/png"); 

      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri); 
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));
```